# Sending a HTTP request after an action has occurred

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a component with an action.  After the action has occurred, I'd like to send a `PATCH` request to an API endpoint. `/posts/{id}`.

How is this accomplished?

My component code `app/components/post.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    isLiked: false,
    actions: {
        toggleLiked() { this.toggleProperty('isLiked'); }
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you use ember data? Or do you want to sent just a normal AJAX request?

Comment: @Lux I'm using ember-data.  With a JSONAPI 1.0 REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `ember-data` you probably already have a post model.
So I assume you call your component like this:

```
{{my-post-component post=model}}
```

If you do so you can just change the model and then call `.save()` in your action:

```
actions: {
  toggleLiked() {
    get(this, 'post').toggleProperty('isLiked');
    get(this, 'post').save(); // this will make the PATCH
  }
}
```